# Cannot get the value in response.body() after making the class type generic

Tags: android, generics, kotlin, retrofit

I'm trying to fetch data from a server using retrofit. I have used generics since I don't want to have repetitive code in my project. However, I am unable to get the values inside of my response body when the type is T. I am only able to access it when I write the class name of my server response specifically.

This is my code:

```
 private fun <T> requestFun(call: Call<T>, default: T) {

                call.enqueue(object : Callback<T> {
                    override fun onResponse(call: Call<T>, response: Response<T>) {
                        response.body()
                    }

                    override fun onFailure(call: Call<T>?, t: Throwable) {

                    }
                })

            }
```

This is my model:

```
data class JsonResponse<T>(
    var data: List<T>? = null,
    var success: Boolean = true)
```

I want to be able to get the list of data back using response.body.result. However this doesn't work since in the function I am getting the type as generic and not JsonResponse!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably use it like this:

```
 private fun <T> requestFun(call: Call<T>, onSuccess: (T) -> Unit) {
     call.enqueue(object : Callback<T> {
         override fun onResponse(call: Call<T>, response: Response<T>) {
             onSuccess(response.body())
         }

         override fun onFailure(call: Call<T>?, t: Throwable) {

         }
     })
```

Then you could do

```
 requestFun<MyClass>(myCall) { myClass: MyClass ->
      ...
 }
```

Of course, this doesn't have any error handling, but it is a possibility.

---

In your case you're not actually receiving `T`, you are receiving `JsonResponse<T>` for whatever unknown reason, so you could do this:

```
 private fun <T> requestFun(call: Call<JsonResponse<T>>, onSuccess: (List<T>) -> Unit) {
    call.enqueue(object : Callback<JsonResponse<T>> {
         override fun onResponse(call: Call<JsonResponse<T>>, response: Response<JsonResponse<T>>) {
             val body = response.body()
             onSuccess(body.data ?: Collections.emptyList())
         }

         override fun onFailure(call: Call<JsonResponse<T>>?, t: Throwable) {

         }
    });
 }
```